# Node-highcharts module not found

Tags: node.js, highcharts

I am trying out the `node-highcharts` library for making PNG's of charts.

My issue is as I have installed the module and run the very basic Node.js Highchart code, I get the error that it can't find the `node-highcharts` module yet I can see it's installed in the module folder, name matches and everything.

I don't understand what is wrong.

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'node-highcharts'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Cormak\Desktop\MM\Dropbox\Work\Afsluttende p
rojekt\SpillerStats\HC TEST\HC.js:2:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Comment: Have you installed it via npm? Where is the module?, you said it was in the 'module folder', do you mean `node-modules' ? You path looks a bit akward to me because of the Dropbox, have you tested it in another location?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the following code in your terminal

```
npm install -g node-highcharts
```

also refer the link below

https://github.com/davidpadbury/node-highcharts